# Edittext remove textchangedlistener

Tags: android, android-edittext, addtextchangedlistener

I've been looking for answers on how i can remove my text change listener.

here is my current code:

```
 public void enableTextChangedListener(boolean enableFormatting){
        if (enableFormatting) {
            if (!"1".equals(mAmountEditText.getTag())) {
                mAmountEditText.addTextChangedListener(new StringUtils.NumberTextWatcherForThousand(mAmountEditText));
                mAmountEditText.setTag("1");

  }
        }
        else {
            mAmountEditText.removeTextChangedListener(new StringUtils.NumberTextWatcherForThousand(mAmountEditText));
        }
    }
```

When my boolean enableFormatting is False, the textchangelistener is still there.

i can provide the class NumberTextwatcherForThousands if you want for more clearer explanation of my code.

Comment: You're creating a new `NumberTextWatcherForThousand` each time `enableTextChangedListener()` is called. When you call `removeTextChangedListener()` with a new, unused `NumberTextWatcherForThousand`, it won't find it to remove, so nothing really happens. You need to keep reference to the `NumberTextWatcherForThousand` you pass in the `addTextChangedListener()` call.

Comment: How can i do that? i'm sorry i dont know @MikeM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the listener, right now you are creating a new listener when you are trying to remove the old one.
Something like this:

```
textWatcher = new StringUtils.NumberTextWatcherForThousand(mAmountEditText);
public void enableTextChangedListener(boolean enableFormatting){
    if (enableFormatting) {
        if (!"1".equals(mAmountEditText.getTag())) {
            mAmountEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            mAmountEditText.setTag("1");

}
    }
    else {
        mAmountEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it says that the : textWatcher = new StringUtils.NumberTextWatcherForThousand(mAmountEditText) where mAmountEditText is always null. im using butterknife anyway.